# Syntax error when importing CSV file (Python)

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I'm fairly new to Python and am using it for parsing some data. For some reason when I run:

import numpy as np

```
def main():

    try:
        sequencename, modelaccession, modelname, bitscore, e-value, -, hmmstart, hmmend, hmmlength, strandofhit, alignmentstart, alignmentend, envelopestart, envelopeend, sequencelength, descriptionoftargetsequence = np.loadtxt(('7202HEVRK3.csv')
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ,delimiter= ','
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ,unpack = True
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ,dtype='string')

        print sequencename

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

I am getting a syntax error.  If someone could help me I would be forever grateful. This is the file name: 7202HEVRK3 (and it's a CSV format).

Edit: The syntax error is "invalid syntax"

Comment: Can you add the complete traceback?

Comment: What syntax error do you get?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign to a minus sign?

Comment: You cannot use a dash (minus sign) in a variable name. Also, you should try to make your code conform to PEP8 standards as it would be much easier to ring that multivariable assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error is occurring because you are trying to assign a value to `-` (the minus operator). By changing `-` to `_` the syntax error will be removed as python reads `_` as a placeholder. It is likely that you intended to do this but forgot to hit the shift button.
Also remove the `-` from `e-value` and replace it with a `_`.

Try the following:

```
try:
    sequencename, modelaccession, modelname, bitscore, e_value, _, hmmstart, hmmend, hmmlength, strandofhit, alignmentstart, alignmentend, envelopestart, envelopeend, sequencelength, descriptionoftargetsequence = np.loadtxt('7202HEVRK3.csv',
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                delimiter= ',',
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                unpack = True,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                dtype='string')

    print sequencename

except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

Comment: A little explanation to highlight the change of a `-` to a `_` would be helpful (and even better, an explanation as to why)

Comment: Thank you. Please see the edited version of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot.

Comment: You still try to use `e-value` as a variable name.